# Java - literals optimalization, test behaviour

Tags: java, jvm, literals

I have a small program testing literals behaviour in Java.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "foo";
    String b = "foo";
    String c = new String("foo");

    System.out.println(a == b);
    System.out.println(a.intern() == b);
    System.out.println(a.intern() == a);
    System.out.println(a == c);
    System.out.println(c == b);
}
```

The results are:

```
true
true
true
false
false
```

The bytecode (javap -c MyClass)

```
   public MyClass();
  Code:
   0:   aload_0
   1:   invokespecial   #1; //Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   4:   return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
   0:   ldc #2; //String foo
   2:   astore_1
   3:   ldc #2; //String foo
   5:   astore_2
   6:   new #3; //class java/lang/String
   9:   dup
   10:  ldc #2; //String foo
   12:  invokespecial   #4; //Method java/lang/String."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   15:  astore_3
   16:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   19:  aload_1
   20:  aload_2
   21:  if_acmpne   28
   24:  iconst_1
   25:  goto    29
   28:  iconst_0
   29:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   32:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   35:  aload_1
   36:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/String.intern:()Ljava/lang/String;
   39:  aload_2
   40:  if_acmpne   47
   43:  iconst_1
   44:  goto    48
   47:  iconst_0
   48:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   51:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   54:  aload_1
   55:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/String.intern:()Ljava/lang/String;
   58:  aload_1
   59:  if_acmpne   66
   62:  iconst_1
   63:  goto    67
   66:  iconst_0
   67:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   70:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   73:  aload_1
   74:  aload_3
   75:  if_acmpne   82
   78:  iconst_1
   79:  goto    83
   82:  iconst_0
   83:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   86:  getstatic   #5; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
   89:  aload_3
   90:  aload_2
   91:  if_acmpne   98
   94:  iconst_1
   95:  goto    99
   98:  iconst_0
   99:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Z)V
   102: return

}
```

Questions)

1) I see that `system.out.println` confirms, that a and b are the same objects
What are the difference between:
`System.out.println(a == b);`
        `System.out.println(a.intern() == b);`

2) Is the `String` optimalization is working becaouse JVM puts the same `String` literals in NonHeap-PermanentGeneration-InternedStrings? Is that why InternedString were created? Then why even without `a.intern()` this is equal: `a==b`

Answer (score 2):

> What are the difference between: System.out.println(a == b); System.out.println(a.intern() == b);

Only that the second involves an entirely unnecessary method call.

> Is the String optimalization is working becaouse JVM puts the same String literals in NonHeap-PermanentGeneration-InternedStrings? Is that why InternedString were created? Then why even without a.intern() this is equal: a==b

Because the compiler and JVM work together to automatically intern string literals. The compiler puts them in a section of the class file calls the "[constant pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4)," and the JVM [loads those constants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3) into the intern pool when the class is loaded.

---

Just for clarity for casual readers: The correct way to compare strings in Java is to use the `.equals` method or similar, not `==`. Using `==` with string instances is *usually incorrect*. The OP is presumably using it here in an effort to understand how and when strings are interned; in real code, you wouldn't. (Similarly: `new String("foo")` is almost always at best unnecessary, and more likely actively a bad idea. Again unless you're playing around with when and how strings are interned.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so how should I understand the InternedStrings (are they related somehow to the program I wrote?), I read about them here: http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html#string_table

Comment: @user1308908: `a` and `b` refer to the **same** string object, because the compiler sees the literals and puts one entry in its constant pool and makes `a` and `b` equal (they contain the same reference). The string you create for `c` is *not* in the constant pool because you're explicitly creating it at runtime (using an initial value that *is* in the constant pool, whose characters are copied). Because the compiler and JVM don't intern `c`, and you never do, it cannot by definition be `==` to `a` or `b`, which have been interned. It's always going to be a different `String` object.

Comment: Thanks again, i understand why c != a but I dont understand the JVM architecture - on the top picture here: http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html Constant Pool is in Method Area and Interned Strings are something above, does it mean that ConstantPool References InternedStrings somehow and when I would create String a = "a"; and in some other class String b="a"; they would be the same objects stored in two ConstantPolls of thes two classes or in InternedStrings?

Comment: @user1308908: I don't know the details beyond the sections of the relevant specifications I linked above. The reason I don't know is there's no reason for me to know. :-) The JVM has been thoroughly optimized, reviewed by experts, and doesn't do dumb things (for instance, make duplicate copies of strings). It provides an intern pool that it puts literals in and that I can add long-lived strings to if desired. That's all I need to know to do my job. I can't really see much reason to delve deeper unless I'm writing a JVM. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I wrote two classes with String a = "a" and its the same object in all three classes called from some JUnit, so as I suspected, this is optimization beyond one class instace. One more question - does VM optimize only Strings in this way or maybe some other objects too ?

Comment: @user1308908: In *this* way, it's just strings. The JVM also caches a small number of instances of `Integer` and `Long` and such wrapper classes for small/common values, which it uses when it can. For instance, the `Integer` instance you get back from `Integer.decode` may be a cached one, or may not, depending on the value. Since those instances are immutable, like `String`s, that's fine. But it's a fairly small number, I think the values -127 through 127 or something like that.